# suddenly frequent "Interrupted system call" return in ZMQ's poll()

Tags: c++, system-calls, zeromq

I know, that EINTR return in ZMQ's poll() function is no problem and usually a retry succeeds, but (!) my system ran months without any appearance of this error and suddenly (since about a week) I get hundreds of them in 1 hour.

Also the behavior somethimes disappears again and the program runs without EINTR for some time. Just while writing, I have a performance test run and after some minutes of work, showing ~100 EINTR, it now continues to run without any EINTR (since about 10 minutes).

the system environment is as follows:

- Windows 10 running a VM under VM Player Version 17 (newest)
- in the VM an Ubuntu 20.4 LTS is installed (current kernel 5.15.0-67-generic freshly updated, problem persists)
- pure C++ code

I recently exchanged the mysql classes in a cleanup session, but cannot believe, that this is related. I had this problem 3 years ago and it magically disappeared. Now it magically reappeared and I have no idea, what could have cause such issue.
It doesn't matter whether I execute my programm under Eclipse or outside, with or without debugger, with or without activated Sanitizer.

Did someone recognize similar problems, maybe due to a system update or likewise?

Comment: strace should enable you to see the signals delivered to your program, propably that will help you(or us) to unterstand what cause the behaviour.

Comment: strace did not reveal anything: 

`>grep -c "Interrupted system call" debug.log`gave 1229, while `grep -c EINTR strace.log` gave only 1 ... doesn't match

Comment: That are only the errors you get back to the application, but what strace should contain are information about the signals that are delivered to you program at the time when you get the error code.

Comment: maybe I'm thinking in the wrong direction, but if "my" error occurs more than 1000 times and is indeed triggered by an event reaching my code, shouldn't strace then show the ~same number of EINTR events? Indeed, the only EINTR that shows up in the strace output is at the time when I hit Crtl-C because I already had those 1229 errors and thought they should be enough examples !?! Sorry if I'm a bit dump here, never used strace before.

Comment: EINTR is the error code that tells you that a system call was aborted by a signal send to your process. And strace can list the list signal send to your process. So you have to search strace for any signal at the correct time, because any (most?) signal will cause an EINTR (ERROR INTERRUPTED) return code.

Comment: did so: after identifying the lead-in of loading libs etc. (my testrun was running under `perf` :-/ sorry) there are ONLY lines containing write(...) and poll(...) until my own Ctrl-C caused that EINTR and directly after that the program quits expectedly due to SIGTERM.
There is nothing else visible in the strace log. Do I need to use special flags to enable such analysis?  I couldn't find related flags to strace.

Comment: I just found a check in one of the sub libraries build config to enable Sanitizer (all other were disabled days ago). since then there were no more EINTR visible. I'll answer this question in case this stays stable for some days.

Comment: @Synopsis hello, did you figure out what was the issue with repetitive EINTR errors from zmq poll?

Comment: Alas: no. I switched Sanitizer on and off, but the EINTRs did not return. Its still very strange that this behavior shows up from time to time and keeps magically disapearing again.